# React state won't update from within a useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using the following code to render a Material UI `AutoComplete` field with options retrieved from an API. I would like to prevent re-rendering of the input field but the chosen country is used as a `prop` for the `Country` component which should be updated `onChange`. `set_alpha3Code` doesn't seem to update the state from within `useCallback`. How do I get around that?

```
let AC = memo(AutocompleteCountries)

function Show(props: {})
{
    let [alpha3Code_, set_alpha3Code_] = useState<string>('gbr');

    let onChange = useCallback((alpha3Code) => {
        console.log(alpha3Code_);
        set_alpha3Code_(alpha3Code);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <AC onChange={onChange}/>
            {alpha3Code_ ? <Country cca3_={alpha3Code_}/> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This is basically a "stale state" issue. There has to be a good dupetarget for it if anyone can find it...

Comment: Can you please share your AutocompleteCountries component?

Answer (score 1):

Two things jump out about that code:

- `onChange` without `value`
- Stale state

### `onChange` without `value`

In the normal case, if you specify `onChange` with an input control, you have to specify `value` to tell the control what the current (updated) value is. [The documentation](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#controlled-states) for Material-UI's `Autocomplete` definitely suggests you need both:

> **Controlled states**
>
> The component has two states that can be controlled:
>
> 1. the "value" state with the `value`/`onChange` props combination. This state represents the value selected by the user, for instance when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The same thing with a standard `input` prevents the input from ever changing. I haven't used the Material-UI `Autocomplete`, but I suspect it's similar.

### Stale state

Your code **is** updating the value of `alpha3Code_` (if `onChange` is called with a new value), but the `console.log` in that code looks at at an old one:

```
let onChange = useCallback((alpha3Code) => {
    console.log(alpha3Code_);       // <−−− Uses the *first* `alpha3Code_` only
    set_alpha3Code_(alpha3Code);
}, []);
// ^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− Because you haven't included
//                                          `alpha3Code_` in these dependencies
```

But even though that `console.log` shows you outdeated information, the rest of the code is fine and will work. It will re-render the `AC` with the updated code.

If you want to see the `alpha3Code_` used for rendering, put a breakpoint on the `return` and look at it in the debugger (or move the `console.log` outside the `onChange` handler to above the `return`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I may be looking at the old value there but I should definitely be using the updated value during the `<Country/>` render but it doesn't seem to be the case. The alpha3Code_ never moves past its default 'gbr' value no matter how many times a change is triggered. I don't want to rerender AC at all since it will fetch data from the API.

Comment: @George -  I've updated the answer. I think you probably are stuck with re-rendering the Autocompleter because if you specify `onChange`, I'm 90% sure you have to specify `value`...and of course that will re-render it. It should be possible to load the information from the API once on mount, not on each re-render. I'm sure the Material-UI Autocompleter is smart enough to do that.

Comment: @George - I think that's the problem, you need to have a `value` prop there.